# how to programmatically check availability of internet connection using jquery

Tags: jquery, android, ajax, cordova

I am developing android phonegap application.When i run the application without internet connection,it is force closed.so,I need to check the internet connection in the dom,before calling the ajax using jquery/javascript

Here is my sample code:

```
var a=navigator.onLine;
 if(a){
  alert('online');
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url, 
            dataType: 'json',
            async: true, 
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){ 

                alert('success');
            },
            error: function(e){

                alert('error');
            }
    });
 }else{
  alert('ofline');
 }
```

But Am always getting the alert('online'),even when there is no internet connection.Please kindly guide me.Thanks in Advance

Comment: Your ajax statement is in the wrong place. It wants to be just below the alert ('online')

Answer (score 8):

As you specified in a tag, you can't access hardware specs without **PhoneGap API**, and to check the Available connection all you need is implement the Connection

> The `connection` object gives access to the device's cellular and wifi connection information.

```
function checkConnection() {
    var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;

    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

    alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
}

checkConnection();
```

Full Example available in [PhoneGap Docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_connection_connection.md.html#Connection)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I have added this code.But in the alert always I am getting 'Cell 3G connection' even when there is no internet connection.Please kindly guide me.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you will **always have 3G connection** that is used through you data connection for your subscription! You need to say that you do not want 3G data... I know how to do it on the iPhone, but not on the Android... search for it. In the emulator, just disconnect from the internet to test it.

Comment: Thanks.I have disabled the data-enabled settings in android emulator and while running the application, i am getting connection type:undefined .please guide me.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could use the device's network connection state property:

```
var a = (navigator.network.connection.type != Connection.NONE);
```

Also see the ["Connection" API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.4.1/phonegap_connection_connection.md.html#Connection)