# How can I check network availability before making a call?

Tags: android, call, offline

I want to make a call, but before this operation I must be sure the mobile network is available and that the phone is not in flight mode.

How can I do this?

Comment: You mean plain old mobile network? or is this a call over the internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` permission in your manifest and then use this:

```
public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    // if no network is available networkInfo will be null, otherwise check if we are connected
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

For all types of connections you can try to use this(`java script`) :

```
function checkConnection() {
    var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;

    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

    alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
}

checkConnection();
```

> The **connection** object gives access to the device's cellular and wifi
>   connection information.

References:
[vogelle-de](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidNetworking/article.html)
[how to programmatically check availability of internet connection using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9478010/how-to-programmatically-check-availability-of-internet-connection-using-jquery)

Comment: **thanks but your code return false for 2G networks.**